# Unwanted dollar symbol when using printf

Tags: java

When I write:

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", 31.0/4.0);
```

it gives me `7$750`

Why does the dollar(`$`) symbol appear instead of a dot(`.`)?

Answer (score 2):

It a `Locale` problem. You need to change the `Locale`.

```
System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.3f", 31.0/4.0);
```

You can verify the problem using:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: @Paul please post the result of `Locale.getDefault`, I am curious to see what locale could do that...

Comment: It is pt_PT (Portugal)

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I doubt this is the default behavior... you might have edited the locale of the system, or a bug on your JVM version?

Comment: @AxelH You are right, this is not a default behaviour because the decimal separator for [`pt_PT` is `,`](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/pt-PT/index.html)

Comment: I have the last JDK and JRE installed and I use eclipse... installed everything by default...

Comment: @PaulDrujco Not sure how this behaviour is occurring but you can use `NumberFormat` / `DecimalFormat` classes to make the results consistent for every `Locale`.